# PHP - Get class by included url

Tags: php

I want to getting class by included url between two hosts , I had to called class , there is a point which i have to creating an API , like a library to calling whatever. or it must be do by another way ?!

call.php

```
<?php  

class call{
    public function Call_Name($c = "") {
        $c = "Called";
        return $c;
    }
}

?>
```

index.php

```
<?php

include 'http://example.com/new/call.php';
$call = new call();
echo $call->Call_Name();

?>
```

(allow_url_fopen , allow_url_include) is already on.

Comment: This question makes no sense to me.

Comment: First thing, `require_once 'call.php'; Not include, and not a url

Comment: `include 'http://example.com/new/call.php'` will include whatever the web server for `example.com` returns for that URL. Go ahead, open it in a browser. See if that server spits out any PHP code…

Comment: *like a library to calling whatever.* - Can we just answer to this kind of questions with "you can do *whatever*"?

Comment: @delboy1978uk I'd explained

Comment: that function takes in a string, and overwrites it with Called, and returns it. Why even use that?

Comment: To include a remote class, you need to have `allow_url_include` on which you already have, so it should work by now. If it's not working, tell us in the question the error message or what is happening, and what you expect to happen.

Comment: Edson, calling a URL never returns PHP code. PHP must die when the response is generated. Request, PHP, Response. It returns text/html, application/json, etc, but not plain PHP code.Unless the server isn't processing php and just serves it like a text file then i guess that would work. Not often you see that though. Because it's not a good idea to make your business logic public facing

Comment: Actualy there is all i want  creating a sources , using it and returning code

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for just isn't safe.

Instead of attempting to execute remote code, consider using a package manager such as Composer/Packagist. You can write your general classes once as a "library" and share them among your "packages".

Take a look here: https://getcomposer.org/ for how to get started.

Comment: is a safe way ?

Comment: is there a safe way? of running arbitrary remote code? from a trusted source? yes, use a package manager, download it and update as you need. If it isn't run it a sandbox... but to include it in your application could lead to any number of issues